# Does Magento 1.9.2.4 include SUPEE-3941 patch?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

I need to know if it is necessary to install SUPEE-3941 patch on Magento 1.9.2.4.

I am asking this because I just received Magento notification email to update SUPEE-8788 to version 2 and instructions state that it is necessary to apply SUPEE-3941 before updating SUPEE-8788 to version 2.

But **SUPEE-3941 is available only for Magento 1.8.0.0 and 1.9.0.1.**

Should I install it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to install SUPEE-3941 on Magento 1.9.1.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you. Just a consideration though, should not be SUPEE-3941 patch added in the "included patches" notes under the Magento 1.9.2.4 download section?

Comment: @Antony yes 100% agreed, Magento should have added that to the list

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism should i install the SUPEE-3941 if i want to install the SUPEE-8788 for magento 1.9.2.4? because in download page for SUPE-8788 it says you need to install SUPEE-3941 if your magento version doesn't include this patches

Answer (score 1):

you can check in [this](https://www.magereport.com/) website that how many security patches you missing.

I think in mgaento 1.9.2.4 you already have this patch but for safer side you can check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had already checked on magereport, just wanted this question confirmed.